# app with tab bar and navigation bars

Tags: iphone, tabs, navigation

[image]

Hi all,
         this is a typical layout of one of apps. Now what I want on clicking of row of one of the view controllers(table view), I want to change the index of of the tab. Lets say I am in 3rd view, I want to move to the 1st view.

I tried with navigation controller's `didShowViewController` delegate method. Seems its not working. Could you please suggest any other way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the below code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of UITableView, then you just need to set the SelectedIndex for Tabbar.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```